# Resources$NotFoundException is thrown by Integrating Facebook-android-sdk-3.0

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-resources

I'm trying to integrate Facebook inside my app. But as soon as i clicked on `fbphoto` it throws error `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`. I do know that it throws error as proper resource is not founding at runtime.

Found out that error is thrown at `facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {}`. But the root cause is still missing.

```
fbphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });

public void loginToFacebook()
{
if(!facebook.isSessionValid())
    {
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {

        });
    }
```

---

```
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050011
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:254)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:183)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.onCreate(WebDialog.java:188)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$WebViewAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:462)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:210)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:189)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:117)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:98)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.Session.tryLegacyAuth(Session.java:1096)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.Session.authorize(Session.java:893)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:957)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.Session.openForPublish(Session.java:415)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.openSession(Facebook.java:319)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:313)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:149)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.example.splashscreen.SecondScreen.loginToFacebook(SecondScreen.java:110)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.example.splashscreen.SecondScreen$1.onClick(SecondScreen.java:73)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-08 02:57:58.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the stacktrace, the error is caused by this line :

```
spinner.setMessage(getContext().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loading));
```

source code is [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java)

The resource is correctly defined in [res/values/string.xml](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/res/values/strings.xml)

Obviously, the error is not in the facebook-android-sdk.

I guess there is a probem with your project setup. You can follow this [guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) to setup your project properly.

Comment: I was pulling my hair since few hours. Thanks for guiding on to very proper direction.

Answer (score 8):

Please note that this error will also happen if you are running IntelliJ and have included the Facebook source as a library module in your project.

It's unclear what actually *causes* this to occur, but when the Facebook project (entire tree) is included as a library module in your IntelliJ project, the facebook strings.xml file will sometimes get overwritten with a very simple strings.xml file, and break your app with the Resources Not Found exception on the Facebook login screen.  Not only that, but the Facebook AndroidManifest will sometimes also get overwritten and cause compile time issues.

Replacing the bogus strings.xml and AndroidManifest.xml files will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you. this solved my problem. I'm really mad on IntelliJ for this one.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  I chased this for nearly an entire day till I found this answer.

Comment: I deleted the facebook sdk folder 3 or 4 times and then realized that Intellij indeed does that evil thing. This is so insane